# Sequence of functions iteratively defined

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I would like to iteratively define a vector of functions (called `copies` in the following) depending on a parameter `s` and a vector `c`. The iterative step looks like this:

```
f[s_, c_] := s + copies[[i - 1]][c[[i]], c];
```

I guess the main issue here is that the function from the previous step is evaluated at `[c[[i]], c]`, with `c` being the vector on which the new `f` depends.

Here comes a prototype of the .nb I would like to evaluate.

```
k = 6;
copies = Table[r, {i, 1, k}];
cev = {1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4};

f[s_, c_] := s + c[[1]];
copies[[1]] = f;

copies[[1]][0.9, cev] (*this works and is evaluated to 0.9+1=1.9*)

For[i = 2; i++, i <= k,

  f[s_, c_] := s + copies[[i - 1]][c[[i]], c];
  copies[[i]] = f;

  ];

copies[[4]][2, cev]   (*Evaluation never gets to this point.*)
```

What is the correct way of carrying out such a task?
Thank you.

Comment: I am not quite able to follow what you are trying to do but I notice that the step `copies[[1]][0.9, cev]` present for the case `i=1` is missing in your `For` loop. The problem that you are experiencing may be related to that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but my interpretation is that you want to generate an indexed set of functions definitions like so:

```
cev = {1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4};
k = Length[cev];

Clear[f]
f[1][s_] = s + cev[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= k, i++,
  f[i][s_] = s + f[i - 1][cev[[i]]]]
```

This gives the definitions

```
Definition @ f
```

[image: defs]

and

```
{f[1][.9], f[4][2]}
```

gives

> `{1.9, 8}`

However, the same set of indexed function definitions can be produced with

```
Clear[f]
f[1][s_] = s + cev[[1]];
Do[f[i][s_] = s + f[i - 1][cev[[i]]], {i, 2, k}]
```

or

```
Clear[f]
MapIndexed[(f[#2[[1]]][s_] = #1 + s) &, Accumulate[cev]];
```

both of which show better Mathematica practice than the For-loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the edit. What I need to get at the end is an indexed set of functions depending on both `s` and the vector `c`. At each iteration the argument `s` of the function defined for `i-1` is evaluated at `c[[i]]`, which should remain a variable I can set later.

Comment: @Leonardo. Sorry, but your comment makes the underlying algorithm you have in mind totally unclear to me. I think others will be puzzled  as well. I suggest you edit your question so that it shows full worked out example of how `s` can be the argument of the generated function and get its value from 'c[[1[[`, which can change ***after*** the sequence of functions is  generated.